# How did Palpatine manage to enter the world between worlds?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

Just rewatched a few scenes from the episodes featuring the world between worlds.
After seeing it I'm wondering: How did Palpatine enter the world between worlds to almost capture Ezra and Ashoka? OR was it really him at all?

Comment: IIRC, he doesn't enter it himself. He sends his power (in the form of some grasping lightning) apparently by way of some ritual he was performing.

Comment: Going off of what @GeoffAtkins said, The Clone Wars (S6 E13), Palpatine has been shown manipulating the force and messing around with individuals that are effectively 'in another world' through the force. I'd be more specific about the experience, but spoilers!